# Proper usage of Comma fold in parameter pack C++

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, parameter-pack

I have a class with a variadic argument templated constructor and I am trying to separate out the parameter pack one by one and pass it to member `set` function. I tried `std::move` and `std::forward` as well as shown in commented lines.

```
class Builder {
public:
  template <class... Args> Builder(Args... args) {
    // (set(std::forward<Args>(args)), ...);
    // (set(std::move(args)), ...);
    (set(args), ...);
  }

  void set() {}

  void set(int x) { X = x; }

  void set(float y) { Y = y; }

  void set(std::string str) { name = str; }

private:
  int X;
  float Y;
  std::string name;
};

int main() {
  Builder bld1{1, 2.5, "Hello"};
  return 0;
}
```

I get an error saying -

```
call to member function 'set' is ambiguous
    (set(args), ...);
```

Trying to follow the [fold expressions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold) documentation and other online posts, but could not get this resolved.

Comment: You're passing in a double so the compiler probably doesn't know which method to call. What happens if you change `2.5` to `2.5f`?

Comment: Thanks! works now, 
Attention to details

Comment: @Nitron_707 C++ is all about the details... that's what in the end gives you fine control (to get the code to do what you want). Or as someone once said : "Power is nothing without control"